# ionic cordova build ios gives me the following error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Suppose say app name is "My First Ionic App".
when i run the command "Ionic cordova build ios" It gives me the following error.

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/user214378/Desktop/ccd-ionic-final/platforms/ios/build/emulator/ My\ First \ Ionic \ App\ /My\First  \ Ionic \App \ App normal (in target '' from project '')
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build ios exited with exit code 65.
```

Comment: Which version of ionic and ios sdk you are using here? What are the specifications?

Comment: Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.13
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.12
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 10 other plugins)